# Resizing Youtube iframe after superview change using WKWebview

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, video, youtube

I am loading a WKWebview that contains an embedded youtube video using their js sdk. I have three views, an internal container, a full screen container, and an external (airplay mirroring) container that can potentially hold the WKWebview with the video in it.

I can load a video into the WKWebview, and move it from the internal to the fullscreen view just fine, or from the internal to the airplay view, and the video resizes as it's told to and everything works great. Moving back from fullscreen to internal or airplay to internal 5 out of 6 times does not resize the video.

Another tidbit, the exact same container code with the same video running in a UIWebView works just fine, and resizes every time.

Has anyone encountered weirdness like this?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be two things:

1. I needed to add the following into the `<head>` of the page containing the video:

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />`

2. For whatever reason if I had a containing view that was also a property on the controller, and the whole thing got passed around, it sent updates to it's content that it's size had changed and everyone was happy.